# How to create a pluggable components in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, playframework

We are developing many application web services. Most of the Application will have login authentication feature. Instead of writing code all the time for all applications, I am planning to create a pluggable authentication component that can be used with any application with ease.

I had an idea that separating the authentication code (which will check username and password from user table) from an application, create a jar file and we can use that in any application. But we are using different database names for different applications how can I configure database connection string?

We are developing web services using Java Play Framework. We will give database name in the conf/application.conf file.

How can I access different database schema using component?
Is there any standard way in Java to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Context and dependency injection (JSR 330) is a standard way to have your component injectable. 
https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330

If you're developing a JavaEE project, you will have it automatically when deploy to a JavaEE supported server (Wildfly for example).

Another standard which you could make use of is JPA. Using JPA you will be able to use powerful ORM and other operations related to Relational DB.